# Convert decrypted string into JSON object

Tags: ios, swift4.2

After decrypting my response from API i am getting a string `"name:DM100, profile:[1,2,4,5]"`.

How can i convert this to a json object where name is string and profile is an array

i have tried using but getting nil

```
if let data = testString.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        } catch {
            print("JSON Serialization Error :-> \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: You can't use `JSONSerialization` because the string is not valid JSON. All keys and other strings must be wrapped in double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON String is not valid. It should look like this:

```
let testString = "{\"name\":\"DM100\", \"profile\":[1,2,4,5]}"

if let data = testString.data(using: .utf8) {
    do {
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
            print(json["name"])
        }
    }
    catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }
}
```

Start and end with curly braces `{}` and have double quotations around string keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to get the output:

**But String must have and valid JSON format first as follows:**

```
 let string = "{\"name\":\"DM100\", \"profile\":[1,2,4,5]}"
            let data = string.data(using: .utf8)!
            do {
                if let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? Dictionary<String,Any> {
                    print(jsonObj)
                } else {
                    print("JSON Error")
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
```